# A non well formed numeric value encountered on Date()

Tags: php, date

There's lots of questions of StackOverflow about "A non well formed numeric value encountered" but none of them appear to be about the same situation as mine.

I have a server running PHP 5.3.6-6~dotdeb.1 that throws up the above error when it encounters this line:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2016-02-05 12:03:00");
```

It's a simple line that worked previously, but now doesn't. What's going on?

There's no error when I use this line:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2016-02-05 12:03:00"));
```

Comment: Is it literally that line? Or does the date string come from a variable? If so, var_dump() that variable and check the length very closely

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, it's literally that line. (I've tested it to make sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `date` is expected to be a **UNIX timestamp integer**. `"2016-02-05 12:03:00"` is a string, not an `int`, and most certainly not a UNIX timestamp.

To turn a human readable date format into a UNIX timestamp, run it through `strtotime`. To turn a UNIX timestamp into a human readable date, format it with `date`.

Comment: Did it really? Perhaps you were just suppressing errors and never noticed how it screwed up?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine before (and works fine on another server right now). Strange.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that myself now. I've checked the code and it was connected to a function to validate a date -- if the server was suppressing errors, it's possible that it was passing that validation by default (even though the value itself was wrong -- reverting to a 1969 date) and so not causing any issues. In fact, I'm sure that must have been it. Doh. I've corrected the code now as per your explanation.